# PHP add string to first and last

Tags: php

How to add `"` string into the first and last in PHP,

something like this :

```
hello world
```

into like this :

```
"hello" "world"
```

is there before-string and after-string function in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use it like as

```
echo '"Hello" "World"';
```

You can simply use `preg_replace` like as

```
echo preg_replace('/(\w+)/',"\"$1\"","hello world");
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/444924)

Comment: i know that one, of course. but, right now, i got a situation that not allowing me to use this method. is there a function?

Comment: this one is working, thank's you so much Mr. Uchiha! God Bless You!

Answer (score 2):

In PHP there are two basic ways to get output: echo and print.

In this tutorial we use echo (and print) in almost every example. So, this chapter contains a little more info about those two output statements.

For more datailes use http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php 

$str="hello world";//your string
$str=str_replace(" ",'" "',$str); //replace all spaces with " "
echo '"'.$str.'"';//while displaying add double quotes in begning and end.

?>
```

Comment: this one is working, thank's you so much Mr. Suchit! God Bless You!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function.
However you can try using split function on space of the string, then use implode() function with your glue or you can simply try using regex.Latter would give you a 1 line call to do this.